# Error when updating from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

When I want to update Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10, the updater stops and shows me this error:

Error during update :

[image: Please look at this picture]

and I am using old repositories.

What can I do?

Comment: Please refer [http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release]

Comment: Do this - `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and see if the error exists.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old Ubuntu and no longer gets supported from Canonical. Open the Terminal using the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter the command:

```
sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

It will replace all **archive.ubuntu.com** -> **old-releases.ubuntu.com**. This repository **old-releases.ubuntu.com** maintains packages for old Ubuntu versions.

And then enter the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

to fetch the new lists.

Finally, restart your ubuntu upgrade.

**Note**: Instating of using GUI, you can launch following commands one by one to get it to upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Comment: nothing change .  i was using old repository , i do what you post, but again i have same errors , thank you

Comment: By chance, are you accessing internet through a proxy?

Comment: no , i connect from iran . is it problem for this error?

Comment: If you connect to internet through a proxy, you will have to configure APT to have it worked with it. Have you launched `sudo apt-get update` and tried to upgrade by commands I mentioned above?

Comment: yes , i do it , and i have no error .  but in sudo do-release-upgrade i have 404 error very much

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please launch `sudo apt-get dost-upgrade` first and then `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`.

Comment: thank you very much . it work like charm . you solve my problem and now my ubuntu is 13.10 , thank you